# В таблице MySQL присвоить текстовому полю - численный идентификатор

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Как в MySQL текстовому полю с типом автомобилей присвоить численный идентификатор?
Например, есть таблица:

```
+------------+-------------------
| id_model      | Type          |
+------------+-------------------
| 12            | Седан         | 
| 13            | Внедорожник   | 
| 14            | Универсал     |
| 15            | Купе          |  
| ......        | ......        |   
| 2032          | Седан         |  
+------------+-------------------
```

Нужно сделать , чтобы Седан имел идентификатор - 1,  Внедорожник - 2 и т.д.
Чтобы получилось:

```
+------------+-------------------
| id_model      | Type          |
+------------+-------------------
| 12            | 1             | 
| 13            | 2             | 
| 14            | 3             |
| 15            | 4             | 
| ......        | ......        |   
| 2032          | 1             |      
+------------+-------------------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Допустим вашу таблицу с машинами зовут cars

```
CREATE TABLE types(
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
type VARCHAR(20),
PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

INSERT INTO types (type) SELECT type FROM cars;

ALTER TABLE cars CHANGE COLUMN type type_old VARCHAR(20);

ALTER TABLE cars ADD type INT;

UPDATE cars t1, types t2 SET t1.type=t2.id WHERE t2.type=t1.type_old;

ALTER TABLE cars DROP COLUMN type_old;

ALTER TABLE cars ADD FOREIGN KEY (type) REFERENCES types(id);
```

PS только на тестовой таблице сначала проверьте, а то мало ли ошибся где